# Windowsupdate failure for specific packages

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, dism, sfc

A computer at work is driving me batty. It running Win7 x64 Enterprise on a Intel Xeon processor). KB3102429 (v2) has been failing for the past few months, several times a day, cluttering up the HDD with CbsPersist logs. This was also, for some reason, stopping windowsupdate from recognizing and installing other updates to the system.

Installing the CheckSUR tool and running it as `DISM /online /cleanup-image /scanhealth` reveals the root of the problem is really KB3006137.

Downloading the MSU for KB3006137 and placing it at `C:\windows\temp\CheckSUR\Packages` didn't fix it.  Nor did expanding the KB's `msu` and the main `.cab` inside and placing the indicated `mum` and `cat` files into `C:\windows\temp\CheckSUR\servicing\Packages` and the `manifest` files into `C:\windows\temp\CheckSUR\winsxs\Manifests`

I have also attempted to copy the mum, cat and manifest files from another working Win7 box from the appropriate directories in c:\windows to the same directories as above, without any changes seen.

SFC /scannow has been run, but sees associated errors as well that it can't fix. It also seems to "stall" for a long time at 34% complete of the verification phase.

from my CheckSUR.log

```
> Unavailable repair files:
>   winsxs\manifests\x86_microsoft-windows-i..nal-core-locale-nls_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.22919_none_6d4e27ec20a10a6f.manifest
>   winsxs\manifests\amd64_microsoft-windows-i..nal-core-locale-nls_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.22919_none_c96cc36fd8fe7ba5.manifest
>   winsxs\manifests\amd64_microsoft-windows-g..acheclean-lithuania_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.18713_none_3202ae2f5f4287d3.manifest
>   winsxs\manifests\x86_microsoft-windows-i..nal-core-locale-nls_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.18713_none_6cbe877f0788d574.manifest
>   winsxs\manifests\amd64_microsoft-windows-i..nal-core-locale-nls_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.18713_none_c8dd2302bfe646aa.manifest
>   winsxs\manifests\amd64_microsoft-windows-g..acheclean-lithuania_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.22919_none_32924e9c785abcce.manifest
>   servicing\packages\Microsoft-Windows-IE-Hyphenation-Parent-Package-English~31bf3856ad364e35~~~10.2.9200.16437.mum
>   servicing\packages\Microsoft-Windows-IE-Hyphenation-Parent-Package-English~31bf3856ad364e35~~~11.2.9412.0.mum   servicing\packages\Microsoft-Windows-IE-Spelling-Parent-Package-English~31bf3856ad364e35~~~10.2.9200.16437.mum
>   servicing\packages\Microsoft-Windows-IE-Spelling-Parent-Package-English~31bf3856ad364e35~~~11.2.9412.0.mum
>   servicing\packages\Package_3_for_KB3006137~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.0.mum
>   servicing\packages\Package_5_for_KB3006137~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.0.mum
>   servicing\packages\Package_for_KB3006137_SP1~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.0.mum
>   servicing\packages\Package_for_KB3006137~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.0.mum
>   servicing\packages\Microsoft-Windows-IE-Hyphenation-Parent-Package-English~31bf3856ad364e35~~~10.2.9200.16437.cat
>   servicing\packages\Microsoft-Windows-IE-Hyphenation-Parent-Package-English~31bf3856ad364e35~~~11.2.9412.0.cat   servicing\packages\Microsoft-Windows-IE-Spelling-Parent-Package-English~31bf3856ad364e35~~~10.2.9200.16437.cat
>   servicing\packages\Microsoft-Windows-IE-Spelling-Parent-Package-English~31bf3856ad364e35~~~11.2.9412.0.cat
>   servicing\packages\Package_3_for_KB3006137~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.0.cat
>   servicing\packages\Package_5_for_KB3006137~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.0.cat
>   servicing\packages\Package_for_KB3006137_SP1~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.0.cat
>   servicing\packages\Package_for_KB3006137~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.0.cat
```

with the kb3006137 lines above all doubled.

Also, earlier in that log file I saw, for example:

```
(f) CBS MUM Corrupt 0x800F0900  servicing\Packages\Package_3_for_KB3006137~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.0.mum      Line 1: 
(f) CBS Catalog Corrupt 0x800B0100  servicing\Packages\Package_3_for_KB3006137~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.1.0.cat      
(f) CSI Manifest All Zeros  0x00000000  winsxs\Manifests\x86_microsoft-windows-i..nal-core-locale-nls_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.22919_none_6d4e27ec20a10a6f.manifest    x86_microsoft-windows-i..nal-core-locale-nls_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.22919_none_6d4e27ec20a10a6f
```

The CBS.log (from `sfc /scannow` I presume) shows lines such as

```
2016-07-04 10:25:29, Info                  CSI    000008ec Manifest hash for component [ml:280{140},l:196{98}]"x86_microsoft-windows-i..nal-core-locale-nls_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.18713_none_6cbe877f0788d574" does not match expected value. 
 Expected:{l:32 b:b8c2ad60e727ca5c76657b129ef2fff656eb4869ebd9b7f263e14231a3bdc27a}
 Found:{l:32 b:55013a93495ee57fd989597e8fed1c6545748884810dd5be8ccde59578d79a12}.
2016-07-04 10:25:29, Info                  CSI    000008ed Looking for manifest in Backup Dir...
2016-07-04 10:25:29, Error                 CSI    000008ee (F) Unable to load manifest for component [ml:280{140},l:196{98}]"x86_microsoft-windows-i..nal-core-locale-nls_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.18713_none_6cbe877f0788d574"[gle=0x80004005]
2016-07-04 10:25:29, Error                 CSI    000008ef@2016/7/4:18:25:29.587 (F) d:\win7sp1_gdr\base\wcp\componentstore\storelayout.cpp(2714): Store corruption detected in function ComponentStore::CRawStoreLayout::FetchManifestContent expression: 0
  FileHashMismatch on resource [125]"\winsxs\manifests\x86_microsoft-windows-i..nal-core-locale-nls_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.18713_none_6cbe877f0788d574.manifest"[gle=0x80004005]
2016-07-04 10:25:30, Info                  CSI    000008f0 Manifest hash for component [ml:280{140},l:200{100}]"amd64_microsoft-windows-i..nal-core-locale-nls_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.18713_none_c8dd2302bfe646aa" does not match expected value. 
 Expected:{l:32 b:7f0749ae29af9ce244ef228ffff63da5f7f7a9dbbb759e01df257d0b48a35864}
 Found:{l:32 b:baa234c528afba1c334f45fcbaf67e346d3d1873483fd0f6d35aa476cf013575}.
2016-07-04 10:25:30, Info                  CSI    000008f1 Looking for manifest in Backup Dir...
2016-07-04 10:25:30, Error                 CSI    000008f2 (F) Unable to load manifest for component [ml:280{140},l:200{100}]"amd64_microsoft-windows-i..nal-core-locale-nls_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.18713_none_c8dd2302bfe646aa"[gle=0x80004005]
2016-07-04 10:25:30, Error                 CSI    000008f3@2016/7/4:18:25:30.887 (F) d:\win7sp1_gdr\base\wcp\componentstore\storelayout.cpp(2714): Store corruption detected in function ComponentStore::CRawStoreLayout::FetchManifestContent expression: 0
  FileHashMismatch on resource [127]"\winsxs\manifests\amd64_microsoft-windows-i..nal-core-locale-nls_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.18713_none_c8dd2302bfe646aa.manifest"[gle=0x80004005]
...
2016-07-04 12:38:28, Info                  CBS    Client specifies CbsMovePayload, or client is Windows Update, will move payload to system.
2016-07-04 12:38:28, Info                  CBS    Appl: detect Parent, Package: Package_for_KB3102429~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.2.0, Parent: Microsoft-Windows-WinPE-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.7601.17514, Disposition = Detect, VersionComp: EQ, ServiceComp: GE, BuildComp: EQ, DistributionComp: GE, RevisionComp: GE, Exist: present
2016-07-04 12:38:28, Info                  CBS    Appl: detectParent: package: Package_for_KB3102429~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.2.0, no parent found, go absent
...
2016-07-04 12:38:28, Info                  CBS    Appl: detectParent: package: Package_for_KB3102429~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.2.0, no parent found, go absent
2016-07-04 12:38:28, Info                  CBS    Appl: detect Parent, Package: Package_for_KB3102429~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.2.0, Parent: Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.7601.17514, Disposition = Detect, VersionComp: EQ, ServiceComp: GE, BuildComp: EQ, DistributionComp: GE, RevisionComp: GE, Exist: present
2016-07-04 12:38:28, Info                  CBS    Appl: detectParent: package: Package_for_KB3102429~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.2.0, parent found: Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.7601.17514, state: Installed
2016-07-04 12:38:28, Info                  CBS    Appl: detect Parent, Package: Package_for_KB3102429~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.2.0, disposition state from detectParent: Installed
2016-07-04 12:38:28, Info                  CBS    Appl: Evaluating package applicability for package Package_for_KB3102429~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.2.0, applicable state: Installed
...
2016-07-04 12:38:36, Info                  CBS    Extracting all files from cabinet \\?\C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution\Download\ef8e9f7986760b0e041197fb53b94584\windows6.1-kb3102429-v2-x64-express.cab
2016-07-04 12:38:36, Info                  CBS    Plan: Package: Package_for_KB3102429~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.2.0, current: Absent, pending: Default, start: Absent, applicable: Installed, targeted: Staged, limit: Staged
2016-07-04 12:38:36, Info                  CBS    Plan: Package: Package_for_KB3102429~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.2.0, Update: 3102429-417_neutral_PACKAGE, current: Absent, pending: Default, start: Absent, applicable: Installed, targeted: Staged, limit: Staged, selected: Default
2016-07-04 12:38:36, Info                  CBS    Plan: Package: Package_for_KB3102429~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.2.0, Update: 3102429-418_neutral_PACKAGE, current: Absent, pending: Default, start: Absent, applicable: Installed, targeted: Staged, limit: Staged, selected: Default
2016-07-04 12:38:36, Info                  CBS    Appl: detect Parent, Package: Package_for_KB3102429_RTM~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.2.0, Parent: Microsoft-Windows-WinPE-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.7601.17514, Disposition = Detect, VersionComp: EQ, ServiceComp: EQ, BuildComp: EQ, DistributionComp: GE, RevisionComp: GE, Exist: present
2016-07-04 12:38:36, Info                  CBS    Appl: detectParent: package: Package_for_KB3102429_RTM~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.2.0, no parent found, go absent
...
2016-07-04 12:38:36, Info                  CBS    Appl: detectParent: package: Package_for_KB3102429_RTM~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.2.0, no parent found, go absent
2016-07-04 12:38:36, Info                  CBS    Appl: detect Parent, Package: Package_for_KB3102429_RTM~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.2.0, disposition state from detectParent: Absent
2016-07-04 12:38:36, Info                  CBS    Appl: Evaluating package applicability for package Package_for_KB3102429_RTM~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.2.0, applicable state: Absent
2016-07-04 12:38:36, Info                  CBS    Plan: Skipping package since its start state and target state are both absent for package: Package_for_KB3102429_RTM~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.2.0, current: Absent, pending: Default, start: Absent, applicable: Absent, targeted: Absent, limit: Staged
2016-07-04 12:38:36, Info                  CBS    Appl: detect Parent, Package: Package_for_KB3102429_SP1~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.2.0, Parent: Microsoft-Windows-Client-Features-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.7601.17514, Disposition = Staged, VersionComp: EQ, ServiceComp: GE, BuildComp: EQ, DistributionComp: GE, RevisionComp: GE, Exist: present
2016-07-04 12:38:36, Info                  CBS    Appl: detectParent: package: Package_for_KB3102429_SP1~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.2.0, parent found: Microsoft-Windows-Client-Features-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.7601.17514, state: Installed
2016-07-04 12:38:36, Info                  CBS    Appl: detect Parent, Package: Package_for_KB3102429_SP1~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.2.0, disposition state from detectParent: Installed
2016-07-04 12:38:36, Info                  CBS    Appl: Evaluating package applicability for package Package_for_KB3102429_SP1~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.2.0, applicable state: Installed
2016-07-04 12:38:36, Info                  CBS    Plan: Package: Package_for_KB3102429_SP1~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.2.0, current: Absent, pending: Default, start: Absent, applicable: Installed, targeted: Staged, limit: Staged
2016-07-04 12:38:36, Info                  CBS    Plan: Package: Package_for_KB3102429_SP1~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.2.0, Update: 3102429-337_neutral_PACKAGE, current: Absent, pending: Default, start: Absent, applicable: Installed, targeted: Staged, limit: Staged, selected: Default
2016-07-04 12:38:36, Info                  CBS    Plan: Package: Package_for_KB3102429_SP1~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.2.0, Update: 3102429-338_neutral_PACKAGE, current: Absent, pending: Default, start: Absent, applicable: Installed, targeted: Staged, limit: Staged, selected: Default
...
2016-07-04 12:38:36, Info                  CBS    Plan: Package: Package_for_KB3102429_SP1~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.2.0, Update: 3102429-416_neutral_PACKAGE, current: Absent, pending: Default, start: Absent, applicable: Installed, targeted: Staged, limit: Staged, selected: Default
2016-07-04 12:38:36, Info                  CBS    Appl: detect Parent, Package: Package_39_for_KB3102429~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.2.0, Parent: Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.7601.17514, Disposition = Detect, VersionComp: EQ, ServiceComp: EQ, BuildComp: EQ, DistributionComp: GE, RevisionComp: GE, Exist: present
2016-07-04 12:38:36, Info                  CBS    Appl: detectParent: package: Package_39_for_KB3102429~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.2.0, parent found: Microsoft-Windows-Foundation-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.7601.17514, state: Installed
2016-07-04 12:38:36, Info                  CBS    Appl: detect Parent, Package: Package_39_for_KB3102429~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.2.0, disposition state from detectParent: Installed
2016-07-04 12:38:36, Info                  CBS    Appl: Evaluating package applicability for package Package_39_for_KB3102429~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.2.0, applicable state: Installed
2016-07-04 12:38:36, Info                  CBS    Plan: Package: Package_39_for_KB3102429~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.2.0, current: Absent, pending: Default, start: Absent, applicable: Installed, targeted: Staged, limit: Staged
2016-07-04 12:38:36, Info                  CSI    000008f9@2016/7/4:20:38:36.155 CSI Transaction @0x4155460 initialized for deployment engine {d16d444c-56d8-11d5-882d-0080c847b195} with flags 00000002 and client id [26]"TI5.30529005_3689335924:1/"

2016-07-04 12:38:36, Info                  CSI    000008fa@2016/7/4:20:38:36.215 CSI Transaction @0x4155460 destroyed
2016-07-04 12:38:36, Info                  CBS    Appl: Selfupdate, Component: amd64_microsoft-windows-f..etype-timesnewroman_31bf3856ad364e35_0.0.0.0_none_5d68182899def0e2 (6.1.7601.23306), elevation:2, lower version revision holder: 6.1.7601.18528
2016-07-04 12:38:36, Info                  CBS    Applicability(ComponentAnalyzerEvaluateSelfUpdate): Component: amd64_microsoft-windows-f..etype-timesnewroman_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.23306_none_3c2bc66fc90ac00b, elevate: 2, applicable(true/false): 0
2016-07-04 12:38:36, Info                  CBS    Appl: SelfUpdate detect, component: amd64_microsoft-windows-f..etype-timesnewroman_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.23306_none_3c2bc66fc90ac00b, elevation: 2, applicable: 0
2016-07-04 12:38:36, Info                  CBS    Appl: Evaluating applicability block(non detectUpdate part), disposition is: Staged, applicability: NotApplicable, result applicability state: Staged
2016-07-04 12:38:36, Info                  CBS    Appl: Package: Package_39_for_KB3102429~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.2.0, Update: 3102429-91_neutral_LDR, Applicable: NotApplicable, Disposition: Staged
2016-07-04 12:38:36, Info                  CBS    Plan: Package: Package_39_for_KB3102429~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.2.0, Update: 3102429-91_neutral_LDR, current: Absent, pending: Default, start: Absent, applicable: Staged, targeted: Staged, limit: Staged, selected: Default
...
2016-07-04 12:38:36, Info                  CBS    Appl: Selfupdate, Component: amd64_microsoft-windows-f..-microsoftsansserif_31bf3856ad364e35_0.0.0.0_none_a91296064892547b (6.1.7601.19106), elevation:16, lower version revision holder: 6.1.7601.18528
2016-07-04 12:38:36, Info                  CBS    Applicability(ComponentAnalyzerEvaluateSelfUpdate): Component: amd64_microsoft-windows-f..-microsoftsansserif_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.19106_none_874ca59c5ea086b3, elevate: 16, applicable(true/false): 1
2016-07-04 12:38:36, Info                  CBS    Appl: SelfUpdate detect, component: amd64_microsoft-windows-f..-microsoftsansserif_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.19106_none_874ca59c5ea086b3, elevation: 16, applicable: 1
2016-07-04 12:38:36, Info                  CBS    Appl: Evaluating applicability block(non detectUpdate part), disposition is: Staged, applicability: Applicable, result applicability state: Installed
2016-07-04 12:38:36, Info                  CBS    Appl: Package: Package_40_for_KB3102429~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.2.0, Update: 3102429-120_neutral_GDR, Applicable: Applicable, Disposition: Installed
2016-07-04 12:38:36, Info                  CBS    Plan: Package: Package_40_for_KB3102429~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.2.0, Update: 3102429-120_neutral_GDR, current: Absent, pending: Default, start: Absent, applicable: Installed, targeted: Staged, limit: Staged, selected: Default
2016-07-04 12:38:36, Info                  CBS    Appl: detect Parent, Package: Package_41_for_KB3102429~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.2.0, Parent: Microsoft-Windows-ServerFoundation-Base-LanguagePack-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~ar-SA~6.1.7601.17514, Disposition = Detect, VersionComp: EQ, ServiceComp: EQ, BuildComp: EQ, DistributionComp: GE, RevisionComp: GE, Exist: present
2016-07-04 12:38:36, Info                  CBS    Appl: detectParent: package: Package_41_for_KB3102429~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.2.0, no parent found, go absent
...
2016-07-04 12:38:36, Info                  CBS    Appl: detectParent: package: Package_41_for_KB3102429~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.2.0, parent found: Microsoft-Windows-WindowsFoundation-LanguagePack-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~en-US~6.1.7601.17514, state: Installed
2016-07-04 12:38:36, Info                  CBS    Appl: detect Parent, Package: Package_41_for_KB3102429~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.2.0, disposition state from detectParent: Installed
2016-07-04 12:38:36, Info                  CBS    Appl: Evaluating package applicability for package Package_41_for_KB3102429~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.2.0, applicable state: Installed
2016-07-04 12:38:36, Info                  CBS    Plan: Package: Package_41_for_KB3102429~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.2.0, current: Absent, pending: Default, start: Absent, applicable: Installed, targeted: Staged, limit: Staged
2016-07-04 12:38:36, Info                  CBS    Appl: detectParent: package: Package_41_for_KB3102429~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.2.0, parent found: Microsoft-Windows-WindowsFoundation-LanguagePack-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~en-US~6.1.7601.17514, state: Installed
2016-07-04 12:38:36, Info                  CBS    Appl: detect Parent, Package: Package_41_for_KB3102429~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.2.0, disposition state from detectParent: Installed
2016-07-04 12:38:36, Info                  CBS    Appl: Evaluating package applicability for package Package_41_for_KB3102429~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.2.0, applicable state: Installed
2016-07-04 12:38:36, Info                  CBS    Plan: Package: Package_41_for_KB3102429~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.2.0, current: Absent, pending: Default, start: Absent, applicable: Installed, targeted: Staged, limit: Staged
...
2016-07-04 12:38:46, Info                  CSI    00000944 Performing 50 operations; 50 are not lock/unlock and follow:
  PrestageComponent (13): flags: 0 app: (null) comp: Microsoft-Windows-Font-TrueType-TimesNewRoman, Version = 6.1.7601.23306, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral
...
  Stage (1): flags: 8 app: [Microsoft-Windows-GC-CountryCodeCacheClean-Canada, Version = 6.1.7601.19106, pA = PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE_AMD64 (9), Culture neutral, VersionScope = 1 nonSxS, PublicKeyToken = {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, Type neutral, TypeName neutral, PublicKey neutral]) comp: (null) man: @0x25d7158
2016-07-04 12:38:46, Info                  CSI    00000946 Unable to prestage file [l:18{9}]"times.ttf" for component [ml:280{140},l:200{100}]"amd64_microsoft-windows-f..etype-timesnewroman_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.19106_none_3ba227beafed231a".
2016-07-04 12:38:46, Info                  CSI    00000947 The payload directory for the candidate component ([ml:280{140},l:200{100}]"amd64_microsoft-windows-f..etype-timesnewroman_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.23306_none_3c2bc66fc90ac00b") does not exist
...
2016-07-04 12:38:46, Info                  CSI    00000974 Unable to prestage file [l:18{9}]"arial.ttf" for component [ml:280{140},l:194{97}]"amd64_microsoft-windows-font-truetype-arial_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.19106_none_d0b610f6c3f0f390".
2016-07-04 12:38:46, Info                  CSI    00000975 The payload directory for the candidate component ([ml:280{140},l:194{97}]"amd64_microsoft-windows-font-truetype-arial_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.23306_none_d13fafa7dd0e9081") does not exist
2016-07-04 12:38:46, Info                  CSI    00000976 Manifest hash for component [ml:280{140},l:196{98}]"x86_microsoft-windows-i..nal-core-locale-nls_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.18713_none_6cbe877f0788d574" does not match expected value. 
 Expected:{l:32 b:b8c2ad60e727ca5c76657b129ef2fff656eb4869ebd9b7f263e14231a3bdc27a}
 Found:{l:32 b:55013a93495ee57fd989597e8fed1c6545748884810dd5be8ccde59578d79a12}.
2016-07-04 12:38:46, Info                  CSI    00000977 Looking for manifest in Backup Dir...
2016-07-04 12:38:46, Error                 CSI    00000978 (F) Unable to load manifest for component [ml:280{140},l:196{98}]"x86_microsoft-windows-i..nal-core-locale-nls_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.18713_none_6cbe877f0788d574"[gle=0x80004005]
2016-07-04 12:38:46, Error                 CSI    00000979@2016/7/4:20:38:46.695 (F) d:\win7sp1_gdr\base\wcp\componentstore\storelayout.cpp(2714): Store corruption detected in function ComponentStore::CRawStoreLayout::FetchManifestContent expression: 0
  FileHashMismatch on resource [125]"\winsxs\manifests\x86_microsoft-windows-i..nal-core-locale-nls_31bf3856ad364e35_6.1.7601.18713_none_6cbe877f0788d574.manifest"[gle=0x80004005]
2016-07-04 12:38:47, Error                 CSI    0000097a (F) STATUS_SXS_COMPONENT_STORE_CORRUPT #15476152# from CCSDirectTransaction::OperateEnding at index 16 (0x0000000000000010) of 50 (0x0000000000000032) operations, disposition 0[gle=0xd015001a]
2016-07-04 12:38:47, Error                 CSI    0000097b (F) HRESULT_FROM_WIN32(14098) #15466023# from Windows::ServicingAPI::CCSITransaction::ICSITransaction2_AddComponents(Flags = 4, a = @0x8768040, mp = @0x8768840, disp = 0)[gle=0x80073712]
2016-07-04 12:38:47, Info                  CBS    Failed to add one or more component [HRESULT = 0x80073712 - ERROR_SXS_COMPONENT_STORE_CORRUPT]
2016-07-04 12:38:47, Error                 CBS    Failed to complete component closure [HRESULT = 0x80073712 - ERROR_SXS_COMPONENT_STORE_CORRUPT]
2016-07-04 12:38:47, Info                  CSI    0000097c@2016/7/4:20:38:47.955 CSI Transaction @0x4155eb0 destroyed
2016-07-04 12:38:47, Info                  CBS    Perf: Resolve chain complete.
2016-07-04 12:38:47, Info                  CBS    Failed to resolve execution chain. [HRESULT = 0x80073712 - ERROR_SXS_COMPONENT_STORE_CORRUPT]
2016-07-04 12:38:47, Error                 CBS    Failed to process single phase execution. [HRESULT = 0x80073712 - ERROR_SXS_COMPONENT_STORE_CORRUPT]
2016-07-04 12:38:47, Info                  CBS    WER: Generating failure report for package: Package_for_KB3102429~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.2.0, status: 0x80073712, failure source: Resolve, start state: Absent, target state: Staged, client id: WindowsUpdateAgent
2016-07-04 12:38:47, Info                  CBS    Failed to query DisableWerReporting flag.  Assuming not set... [HRESULT = 0x80070002 - ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND]
2016-07-04 12:38:48, Info                  CBS    Failed to add %windir%\winsxs\pending.xml to WER report because it is missing.  Continuing without it...
2016-07-04 12:38:48, Info                  CBS    Failed to add %windir%\winsxs\pending.xml.bad to WER report because it is missing.  Continuing without it...
```

Comment: run inplace upgrade to repair Windows if you tried DISM and checksur: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html

Comment: again, run the inplace upgrade, your Windows is damaged too much

Comment: ok, post this as answer

Answer (score 0):

My department's IT division (which has install media for win7) said the DISM repair (and their subsequent attempts) failed due to lack of initial image file. So, their non-solution was to elect to wipe the MS installation from the disk and then reinstall from a cloned image.

Further, IT told me that they thought the initial problem was with a Dell RAID controller that shipped with (unequal capacity) drives in RAID0/mirrored mode. After reinstalling windows, they broke the RAID0 mirror and returned the computer to me.